# Inverse properties of inequalities

Tags: inequality

Take a simple inequality such as 1 >= 1/x. Just by looking at it we can see that x cannot be any number between 0 and 1-; the solution is 0 > x >= 1.

Now if we multiply both sides of the inequality by x:
(1)x >= (1/x)x
x >= 1
Great, but what happened to x < 0?

If we subtract 1/x from both sides:
1 - 1/x >= 0
(x - 1)/x >= 0
x < 0 satisfies the inequality.
Great, but what happened to x >= 1?

How can the last two inequalities have different solutions from the inequality which they were derived from?

Comment: Note that the conventional meaning of $0\gt x\ge 1$ is that $0\gt x$ **and** $x\ge 1$. That is not what you intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at your inequality, namely $$1\geq\frac 1 x$$

to be solved for every real value of $x$. We make an observation: if $x$ is negative, so is $x^{-1}$, so $(1)$ holds. But if $x$ is negative, $$1\geq \frac1x\not\implies x\geq 1$$

Then, since we want $x<0,x\leq 1$, we conclude $x<0$. Thus, **let's assume** $x>0$, since we have already taken care of $x<0$. Then it **is** true that $$1\geq \frac 1 x\iff x\geq 1$$

The solution set is then $(-\infty,0)\cup [1,\infty)$

The other manipulation was not wrong $$1\geq\frac 1 x\iff 1-\frac 1 x\geq 0\iff \frac{x-1}x\geq 0$$

And when is this last inequality true? Precisely when $x>0, x-1\geq 0$ or $x< 0,x-1\leq 0$. This gives you two solution sets $S'=[1,\infty),S''=(-\infty,0)$ that in turn give $S=S'\cup S''$ as the full solutin set. In this case your mistake was in disregarding $x\geq 1$ as a solution.

Comment: if x - 1 <= 0, then wouldn't S" = (-infinity, 1] ?

Comment: @James Yes, but we also want $x<0$. That is $(-\infty,1]\cap(-\infty,0)=(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: Yes (-infinity, 0) can be implied from x < 0, but how did we actually prove that x < 0, when for x < 0, x - 1 <= 0 ?

Comment: @James Well, if we want $x\leq 1$ **and** $x<0$ then we must have $x<0$. That is, we are looking for solutions of $x\leq 1$ that **also** satisfy $x<0$. Since $x\leq 1$ always implies $x<0$, and we assumed $x<0$ in the first place, the solution set is $\{x<0\}$. Have you ever encountered problems where you have to prove two sets are equal? One usually does by showing $S\subset R$ and $R\subset S$.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to very carefully apply the properties of inequalities:
$$a < b \Rightarrow a + c < b + c$$
$$a < b \textrm{ and } c > 0 \Rightarrow ac < bc$$
(It is a useful exercise to prove both of these, for some appropriate definition of $<$.)

Combining these two properties, we see that if $c<0$, multiplying by $c$ **flips** the inequality:
$$a < b \Rightarrow a + (-b-a) < b + (-b-a) \Rightarrow -b < -a \Rightarrow (-c)(-b) < (-c)(-a) \Rightarrow bc < ac.$$

From here you can understand why you are losing solutions during your manipulations: when you multiply your inequalities by $x$, you are implicitly assuming $x>0$. You have to also take into account the case $x<0$, where your inequalities flip.